# Post to mysql database, no error, not storing data

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have searched but couldnt find anything similar to my problem.

I dont get an error when submitting this and nor does the email store in the table.

Any ideas?

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'leegernomics');
define('DB_USER', 'XXXXXX');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXX');
define('DB_HOST', 'XXXXXX.hostedresource.com');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {

    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

    if (!db_selected) {

        die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
    }

$value = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('$value')";

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_qery($sql)`????? You're actually not running your query...

Comment: You never execute your query. Nor do you check for errors.

Comment: Not to mention you're using a _deprecated_ extension... how many times has this been said in comments already: Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead. `mysql_*` is hopelessly outdated, and will be removed some time in the future. Also google ***SQL INJECTION***, what if I post the email: "'; DROP TABLE users; --"?

Answer (score 0):

Execute your query with this : https://www.php.net/mysql_query

But `mysql` component is now deprecated ... If you want to use this kind of db connector, I advise you to use `mysqli` instead (https://www.php.net/mysqli).

If you want to use a more high level component, PDO could make it : https://www.php.net/pdo